# Using Angular component name in Less stylesheet don't match generated DOM

Tags: css, angular, less

I'm leaning Angular by following Udemy course and I have this style:

```
server dl {
    display: flex;
}
```

and `server` component and it don't work. The style is not applied to html. Because generated style look like this:

```
server[_ngcontent-c1]   dl[_ngcontent-c1] {
  display: flex;
}
```

and DOM look like this:

```
<server _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
   <dl _ngcontent-c1="">
     <dt _ngcontent-c1="">Plantform</dt>
     <dd _ngcontent-c1="">Linux x86_64</dd>
   </dl>
</server>
```

`_ngcontent-c0` instead of `_ngcontent-c1`, why this is happening? Why the style don't match the DOM?

I'm using Angular app using generated by CLI with Less (but I've created component by hand using `server` as selector, the same happen if name is `app-server`).

Why this attribute selectors are added? What about if I use this component in different place? I want to match all elements inside component that's why I've added `server` as selector to always match all inside this component.

How can I use component name that is added to html as root for my whole style? Or is this not good practice in Angular and this is handled other way, if so can someone explain?

Comment: The css is scoped to `_nghost-c1` internally by angular (as you can see) when you write rules in css of that component, so you don't have to write `server` in css. Even if you have to, use `:host` selector. Read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of a component is scoped-automagically / polyfilled by angular (in accordance with [css spec for scoping](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/)) using those attributes you noticed. So basically, you don't have to write `component-name element` when you write css for that component but you can just write:

```
dl {
    display: flex
}
```

Angular will make sure that this style is only applied to `dl` inside `server` by using the generated attributes, it is essentially a polyfill for css scoping. If all your targeted browsers support css scoping natively, you can even set `ViewEnacpsulation.Native`

In some cases where you decide to style the root element, you have to use the special selector `:host`

> The :host selector is the only way to target the host element. You
>   can't reach the host element from inside the component with other
>   selectors because it's not part of the component's own template. The
>   host element is in a parent component's template.

So instead of writing `server {background: red}` you will write `:host {background: red}`

This is also inline with css spec for scoping.

Read more about CSS coping and component based CSS to know more about this strategy.

As a primer read the [base documentation in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Also, note that you can add your css to any global stylesheet like the way you did:

```
server dl {
    display: flex
}
```

Which way to go largely depends on how you plan to manage and scale css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use at .TS file below the class.
This is delete all this `_ngcontent`

```
 @Component
   selector,
   template,
   styles,
```

This code `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`